# getelementbyid not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

HI I am trying to get div from getelementbyid but it isnt working for me this is my code

```
 <body onload="ErrorCheck(-1)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ErrorCheck(var1)
{

    if(var1 = -1)
    {   alert("in function");
        var cont = document.getElementBId('msg');       
        if(cont==null){
        alert("null");
        }
        else{
        alert("not null");
        }
    }
}
</script>
<h1 class="header">Register</h1>
<div id="msg"></div>
</body>
```

after getElementBId is called this function becomes dead as it doesnt go to any if or else. Please check what am i doing wrong here

Comment: because it's not `document.getElementBId` but **`document.getElementById`**

Comment: also, the script tag should be in the '<head>' part.

Comment: @Dementic It still exists onload.

Comment: @Dementic Script tags in the body are perfectly fine. It's good practice to put them in the `head`, but not necessary. [Check the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: ^ And by good practice I mean just convention actually.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I would even say its good practice, html files should contain html. JavaScript should go in it's own file.

Comment: Yes, separate files provide less tag soup and better structure/readability and caching, now for production sites, if you have a script that is only executed in one page, putting it inside the html will provide less HTTP requests (and technically a better practice if the HTML is static). @AshBurlaczenko anyway, script tags in either `head` or `body` are still in the HTML. `:P`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot **y** before `...Id('msg');` :

```
var cont = document.getElementById('msg');
```

Comment: Thankyou for checking for this i have wasted like 2 hours on this and couldnt find this silly mistake. i should get a sleep now

Comment: @AhmedMasud: Don't spend 2 hours looking for mistakes that are solved by taking 2 seconds to look at your developer's console.

Answer (score 2):

Errors Include the following

line 6 is

```
if(var == -1)
```

And the next is

```
document.getElementById // not document.getElementBId
```

Comment: `var1 = -1` is not obligatorily an error, but in this case it's surely an error/typo.